# htaccess 301 redirect root only but exclude all files and subfolders with exceptions

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am not a programmer of `.htaccess` code, I read the other related posts but do not understand them. Non of them do what I need.

I have a Wordpress site that runs on `http://example.com/main` but want to redirect `http://example.com` to `http://otherexample.com/page.php`. Also need that `http://example.com/anyfile` not be redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `example.com` and `otherexample.com` point to different places then try something like the following in the root `.htaccess` file at `example.com`:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ http://otherexample.com/page.php
```

The regex `^/$` matches `/` only, ie. the root directory.

- `^` asserts the start-of-string (ie. URL-path)
- `/` matches a literal slash
- `$` asserts the end-of-string

> **UPDATE:** I found that secondary.com also is redirected.

If you have multiple domains pointing to the same place and you only want to redirect one of them then you'll need to use mod_rewrite to check the hostname first before redirecting.

For example, the following would need to go at the top of the `.htaccess` file *before* the WordPress front-controller:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://otherexample.com/page.php [R=302,L]
```

Note that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path less the slash prefix, hence the regex `^$` (different to the `RedirectMatch` directive), which matches an *empty* URL-path (ie. the root directory only).

Comment: after testing it more closely I found that http://secondary.com also is redirected.

Comment: If you have multiple domains then you'll need to use mod_rewrite instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I don't see why the Cond is ^ negative. If I see the Cond as an AND   then is like ^$ AND ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]

Comment: The Cond is not negative. `^` in regex is the start-of-string anchor. This ensures we match from the _start_ of the `Host` header and don't get partial matches, which could result in false positives, depending on the domains you have (but it is more efficient this way too). But otherwise, yes, this is an AND. `^$` matches against the URL-path and the Cond matches against the hostname.